# Gradle 3.0 Build Error : Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

Migrated the project to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'`. Since then I have been getting this error from gradle

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.a(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.CoreLibraryRewriter$UnprefixingClassWriter.toByteArray(CoreLibraryRewriter.java:152)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:403)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)

FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
```

I have tried **Clean Project > Rebuild Project** multiple times, it does not help.

Here is my build config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    configurations.classpath.exclude group: 'com.android.tools.external.lombok'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    flavorDimensions "default"
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shirish"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 140
    versionName "3.30"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled = false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/pixplicity/android" }
    maven {
        url "http://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
    maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude     'com/google/gdata/util/common/base/UnicodeEscaper$1.class'
        exclude 'com/google/gdata/util/common/base/Escaper.class'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation files('libs/commons-net-3.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    implementation files('libs/PayU-release.jar')
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gdata-contacts-3.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gdata-client-1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gdata-core-1.0.jar')

    implementation project(path:':beewisesdk', configuration:'default')

    implementation('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.gdata'
    }
    implementation('ch.acra:acra:4.7.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json'
    }

    implementation group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.9.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:1.1.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jakob-grabner:Circle-Progress-View:v1.2.9'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPicker:v1.0.10'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
    implementation 'com.cloudinary:cloudinary-android:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
    implementation 'com.kbeanie:multipicker:1.1.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.webengage:android-sdk:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.2'

    // Google Api Client library and Android extension
    implementation ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    //People REST API access
    implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev159-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }

    implementation 'com.droidninja:filepicker:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.MAXDeliveryNG:slideview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.4.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.1.8'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}


android { sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'app/model'] } } }

android { sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/xml'] } } }
android {
sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/anim'] } }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please, let me know if any more details are required. I have tried all the SO questions regarding this issue, nothing works. Need a fresh perspective on this problem. I am also including the dependencies at top-level build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Also, at `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'` I am getting a warning to use the same version and as you can see in my gradle all support dependencies are the same version.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @R2R I have added both the gradle.build files.

Comment: Close the project delete .idea folder from app location and then open this project in android studio.

Comment: @jakirhussain tried that too, did not work.

Comment: Did you try running `./gradlew clean` command. Lately android gradle plugin has issue when updating dependencies, but clean helps

Comment: @blazsolar I tried that too. The clean was successful. But again the execution failed with the same error message.

Comment: Base on the laste sentance of your post i would say that some other dependency is adding `recyclerview` as transitive dependency that is more recent than your version. If you run `./gradlew :app:dependencies` command what is the version of `recyclerview`?

Comment: @ShirishKadam were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @WahibUlHaq no this issue still exists & open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Android Studio 3.1 and its build view I started getting a more comprehensive error `Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/Header;`. Hence I checked the usage of the Class `org.apache.http.Header` which led me to understand that I had multiple apache.http libs and after removing `implementation files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')` the build worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Update Gradle version:**

> Android plugin `3.0.0` requires `Gradle version 4.1` or higher. If you're opening an existing project using `Android Studio 3.0` or later, follow the prompts to automatically update an existing project to the compatible version of Gradle.
>
> To update Gradle manually, edit the URL in `gradle-wrapper.properties` to the following:

```
distributionUrl=\
 https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

**Apply the plugin**

> If you're opening an existing project using `Android Studio 3.0` or later, 
>       follow the prompts to automatically update your project to the latest 
>       version of the Android plugin. To manually update your project, include the maven repo and change the plugin version in your project-level `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
    ...
    // You need to add the following repository to download the
    // new plugin.
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

}

For check Gradle Version :  **File > Project Structure > Project**

Also check this :
 https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

[image]

Comment: Please read the question carefully, all these migration steps have been performed. The error was encountered while executing the 'app' module. This answer does not contribute to the solution in any way.